# Silent download with POST parameters over http/https with php

Tags: php, http, post, https

I have a php script that needs to download a file over http/https and specify POST parameters to a request.

There should be no browser popups, just silent download, for example to ~/.
Unfortunately, wrapping `wget` is not an allowed solution.

Is there any easy way to do this ?

Comment: You can use curl if that is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function — IMO the easiest way to get (or POST) simple content over HTTP (or HTTPS). Example of usage:

   ```php
   <?php
   $opts = array('http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'content' => $body, // your x-www-form-urlencoded POST payload
       'timeout' => 60,
   ));
   $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
   $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);
   ```
2. [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) — another easy way to send POST request. The very basic code example:

   ```php
   <?php
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
   // $body is your x-www-form-urlencoded POST payload
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $output = curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
   ```
3. Any other PHP HTTP client (Zend_Http_Client, HTTP_Client, Whatever_Client) which you have or which you can download.